# Indistinguishable encryptions and CPA-secure example

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, chosen-plaintext-attack, security-definition

Let $ F $ be a PRF and $  G$ be a PRG with expansion factor $n \to n +1  $ For the following encryption scheme, decide whether it has indistinguishable encryptions and whether it is CPA-secure.

Given $k \in \{0,1\}^n  $, to encrypt $m \in \{0,1\}^{2n}  $, parse $ m $ as $ m_1\|m_2 $ with $|m_1| = |m_2| = n  $ then choose uniform $  r \in \{0,1\}^n$ and output the ciphertext $\langle r, m_1 \oplus F_k(r), m_2 \oplus F_k(r+1) \rangle  $

I would need help to give a proof about if this ES is CPA secure or not, or at least some tips/ideas to try by myself first.

Comment: This is CTR mode. see [CPA-security of CTR mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/cpa-security-of-ctr-mode)